# Asynchronous PHP Server side process behavior

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

I have a very strange behavior that I cannot understand how to fix.

Background- (CakePHP 2.5.4)

1. User logs into website and decides to upload a zip file for processing
2. User navigates to bulk upload screen where user is provided with provision to upload zip file
3. User uploads zip file, system extracts files and shows the user a list of contents and asks user if it should proceed with processing
4. User click Process - an AJAX call is triggered and immediately after the user is redirected to another web page and they can continue to do what they want
5. On the server side, the AJAX call triggers a bunch of file conversion, reading etc ultimately resulting in data being stored in the database
6. After the zip file is processed an email notification with the status of each file processing is compiled and sent to the user

Problem -

1. Everything above occurs perfectly but when I try to debug various variables in intermittent stages the variables are displaying as null or blank - but the data does get saved into the database
2. The final status array which has the status of various files being processed is blank and is causing a FATAL error
3. I tried overriding the `AppModel::beforeSave()` method to log the data beign saved and that is also logging blank value but when I check the database the data is indeed being saved

There is almost some ghost like behavior that I dont understand and any insight is appreciated sincerely. More comments inline with code below.

Code:

AJAX call -

```
$('#process-btn').on('click', function() {
    // trigger the AJAX require to process the uploaded file on the server side
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#form').attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
    });

    window.location.replace( $(this).data('url') );
});
```

Controller -

```
myAJAXMethod() {
// 1. end the output bugger
ob_end_clean();
// 2. Send a HTTP header that closes connection
header("Connection: close");
// 3. Tell the current PHP execution script to proceed even if user aborts
ignore_user_abort(true);
// 4. Flush the entire TCP / ouput buffer
flush(); // Unless both are called !
ob_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
// 5. Tell the HTTP connection that current session is closed - this doesnt actually close the user session rather closes the current request/response session
session_write_close();

$filepaths = $this->request->data['files'];
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($filepaths); $i++) {
    $filepath = $filepaths[$i];
    $response = array();

    $xml = $parser->parse($filepath);
    $parsed = $parser->getObjectFromParsedXml($xml);
    $response['parseSuccess'] = $parsed['parseSuccess'];

    array_push($status, $response);
    $this->log($status); // PROBLEM - this is printing out as blank
    $this->log($response); // PROBLEM - this is printing out as blank

    if ($response['parseSuccess']) {
        // Save parsed details in database
        $this->Car->create();
        $this->Car->set('name', $parsed['name']);
        $this->Car->set('model', $parsed['model']);
        $this->Car->set('make', $parsed['make']);

        $this->Car->save(); // This does save
    }
}
}
```

AppModel.php

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    $this->log($this->data); // PROBLEM - doesnt print anything but a save is occurring
}
```

UPDATE: Jan-12-2015

So I updated the AJAX call to be as below and now it works perfectly. However the problem is that the AJAX function does not redirect the user to the next page until the server side PHP script finishes executing (which can be pretty long). It seems like the PHP script needs the client side connection to be held to print out all the log statements correctly. I am trying to figure out why - any ideas?

AJAX call -

```
$('#process-btn').on('click', function() {
    // trigger the AJAX require to process the uploaded file on the server side
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#form').attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            complete: function() {
                window.location.replace( $(this).data('url') );
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the rep to post his a comment so i have to add it as an answer. But from the code you've posted we can't see where the problem variables area being set. Is it possible the variables are being over-written before being sent to your logging function?

Comment: I checked and no this is not the case. Also keep in mind that the right values are being entered into the database so the values are there but for some strange reason they aren't appearing in the log